# Can "&" be part of a form <input> name?

Tags: html

For a HTML GET search request I want to include `pretty&` in the URL parameter since the JSON then returns with newlines. I tried to include `pretty&` in the search `<input>` field, like so:

```
<input id="search-query" type="text" name="pretty&q" class="form-control">
<input id="search-query" type="text" name="pretty&amp;q" class="form-control">
```

("q" is for "query" and is the search string parameter)

However neither of these is displayed properly in the URL; the "&" is replaced/encoded with %26.

How can I keep the "&" intact?

Comment: You can't - it would be separate parameters (ie. `pretty` and `q`) if it was.

Comment: what you're trying to do is conceptually incorrect. If you want to send two get params, use two inputs, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, two input-fields with same id/name will not work correctly.
Also by default, GET takes the input-field values and puts them in the querystring of the url and separates them with '&'. The '&' should not be placed in the 'name' of the input-field, because then it is interpret as part of the name and will be url-encoded. Url encoding represents the '&' as %26.